# Реакция бота на лайк - Python, vk_api

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Хотелось бы узнать. А как сделать так, чтобы бот в ВК писал человеку в лс тогда, когда он ставит  или убирает лайк на посте в группе?
Библиотека vk_api

Допустим, человек ставит лайк на пост в группе, а бот его благодарит его в ЛС.

Answer (score 0):

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

def main():
    vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='your_group_token')

    longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, 'your_group_id')

    for event in longpoll.listen():
        print(event.type)

    main()
```

В настройках сообщества (Работа с API -> Long Poll API) проверьте галочку; Записи на стене: Добавление отметки «Нравится».
Затем поставьте лайк на запись, в консоли высветится событие.

```
if event.type == VkBotEventType.событие:
...
```

Comment: Я делал также сам, но событие лайка не выводится, и пишет, что такого события не существует